# Git commit date as versionName

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I currently use  this to get my commit hash as my versionName. Is there a way to get the commit date and add it to this:

```
 def getCommitHash = { ->
 def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
 exec {
     commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'
     standardOutput = stdout
 }
 return stdout.toString().trim()
```

}

So that I get something like this: `Version: 491a9d0, Date: 7-10-2022`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git provides very flexible configuration to format pretty-printing. You could just use a different git command:

```
git show -s --format="Version: %H, Date: %ci" HEAD
```

which would output something like this:

```
Version: e6b12a79136b513cdca7fd12915dd422f8a3141e, Date: 2022-10-06 18:27:38 +0100
```

Or in your case, to feed it to whatever's running git,

```
commandLine 'git', 'show', '-s', "--format=Version: %H, Date: %ci", 'HEAD'
```

The [documentation for git show](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_pretty_formats) contains more info on how to use placeholders in the format option.

Edit: Swapped the annonations

Comment: Thanks for this information, however when trying this I get this error: > Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128. When executing this in a terminal it works fine, but in code it does not

Comment: That doesn't tell you much about what's causing it, but I would guess it may be the `"` within `'`, try escaping with `\"` or consulting the docs for `exec {}`

Comment: I edited the annonations, this was the error

Answer (score 3):

You can replace your git command with:

```
git log -1 --format="format:%h %cs"
```

The possible options for the format string are given in the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_pretty_formats).

- `%h` gets the short version of the commit hash, which is equivalent to what you're getting from `rev-parse` right now
- `%cs` gets the commit date, in short format (YYYY-MM-DD)